# Express CORS subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have a site —`https://example.com`— that makes calls to an API —`https://api.example.com`—. The API is written in Express, and its using [CORS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to allow the requests from the site:

```
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: "https://example.com",
    })
);
```

The site can be accessed via `https://example.com` or via `https://www.example.com`. As you see, in the API am allowing explicitly the requests coming from the former address, but not from the latter. So if anyone access it via the latter address the requests to the API will be rejected.

What is the usual way to solve that? Allow explicitly both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com`? Or maybe there is a way to ignore the subdomain `www`?

Thanks in advance!

--

EDIT:

As proposed I added `https://www.example.com` explicitly to the cors configuration

```
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: ["https://example.com", "https://www.example.com"],
    })
);
```

But this didn't work. As a workaround what I just did is to redirect with a rewrite condition in `.htaccess` file —Apache server— from `www` domain to non `www` domain.

But the question now is: why even allowing `www.example.com` didnt work? Is there any common reason for that?

Comment: If the site can be accessed at both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com`, then in your npm-cors config, you need to explicitly allow both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com`. There’s no other way to ignore/handle `https://www.example.com`.

Comment: You can specify a regular expression like `https://(www.)example.com` for the npm-cors ‘origin’ value, but the effect of that is gonna be the same as if you just specified an array with the explicit values. And in the end the effect is anyway going to be that the server either sends back `https://example.com` as the explicit value, or it sends back `https://www.example.com`. Browsers treat the value literally — unless the value is the `*` wildcard. And of course as an alternative to specifying allowed origins, you always have the option to specify the `*` wildcard for the ‘origin’ config value

Comment: Ok, then I will set them explicitly. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, setting them explicitly didn't work. As a workaround what I just did is to redirect with a rewrite condition in `.htaccess` file —Apache server— from `www` domain to non `www` domain. But the question now is: even allowing `www.example.com`, why didnt work? I update the question

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way would be to avoid having two websites on different origins with identical content.

Configure `www.example.com` to issue an HTTP 301 redirect to `example.com`.

---

> Allow explicitly both `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com`?

That would work too. `origin` can be passed an array.

> Or maybe there is a way to ignore the subdomain www?

`origin` can also be passed a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! Passing `https://www.example.com` didn't work. I updated the question, because it should, right?

Comment: @Nikita — It should. There's nothing in the question to suggest why it didn't.

Comment: Thanks! Then I will make some tests, probably I'm missing something…

Answer (score -2):

You need to allow both domains. The API for doing this is a bit complicated. Basically you need to read the [documentation of the CORS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors):

```
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: function (origin callback) {
            switch (origin) {
                case "https://example.com":
                case "https://www.example.com":
                    callback(null, true); // allow these domains
                    break;
                default:
                    callback(new Error('Now allowed')); // block others
            }
        },
    })
);
```

The value of `origin` can only be either a string or your own custom logic implemented as a function.

Comment: Isn't this the same as passing the domains as an array with `origin: ["https://example.com", "https://www.example.com"]`?

Comment: Using a function for this is massively overkill